# Ideal location to put BLE linking functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is a question coming from an Android developer who is trying to refactor boilerplate codes written in unfamiliar language (Objective-C). I am quite new to iOS and still have a little knowledge about the framework's lifecycle.

Currently, the implementation of BLE `delegates` is located in the `TabBarController` (main controller) of our project which holds the six `NavigationController` (the two additional tabs are just a hack of the former developer of this project). Each navigation controller will then send a deferred command to the main controller and the issuers should listen accordingly to the response from an external device, if any.

I am thinking of relocating the BLE functions to the`AppDelegate`, which I think is the most persistent location. From there, I will be creating a `sendCommand` function and `delegates` for the navigation controllers to be able to listen to the incoming responses. If this is not, which is the ideal location to put the BLE linking functions?

Comment: as personal opinion : yes, it's a good thing to do, but i don't really have anything to prove my claim. that or create an abstract View Controller that all others extend from that has these methods.

Answer (score 1):

The current situation isn't great, and moving the logic to the app delegate is no better. The app delegate is there to deal with overall application configuration, not Bluetooth.

So, create a new class which is a Bluetooth controller or manager. The app delegate or the tab bar controller could create an instance of this class, but all they do with it is pass it into the view controllers which will actually use it. This is (one form of) dependency injection.